# Load average jumps up during a sort in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have encountered a MySQL query that takes over 2 minutes to complete and brings up the server load very high (e.g. from 2 to 14, or sometimes higher).

The query does a left join between  tables, then sorts the data based on a float column on of the joined tables, like this:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.field, table4.field
  FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1...
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1...
  LEFT JOIN table4 ON table3...
  LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1...
 WHERE table1.deleted=0
 ORDER BY table2.float_field ASC
 LIMIT 1,300
```

The JOINS are all done on indexed keys, and table2 also has an index on the float_field.

The same database structure and query is used on other databases without issues. This table2 is a custom field table, alterable by users of this database, so in this particular system, I see that it has 107 fields, more than 2/3 of them being varchar(150). Would this be why the high load, or is there some other reason? Any suggestion for how to handle it (ideally without having to re-do the db schema)?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here are the 'explain' results:

```
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref             | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 | ALL    | idx_1,idx_2   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL            | 33861 | Using where | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table2 | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 108     | db.table1.id    |     1 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | jtl0   | ref    | idx_X         | idx_X   | 111     | db.table1.id    |     1 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table4 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,...   | PRIMARY | 108     | db.jtl0.field   |     1 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | jt1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 108     | db.table1.fieldX|     1 |             | 
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+-------------+
```

Both idx_1 and idx_2 use 'deleted' column as the first field in the index. There is only this 1 field in the where

I also corrected the original text, there are 5 tables used, not 4 (although the last table has 20 rows only, so it doesn't matter here).

Comment: how are the results used? If they are used in code then there will be a specific list of which columns are accessed for each table? Or is this just a 'display to user all columns in DB' type query ?

Comment: I added the explain results. They are used in code, but at the moment, it looks like the code isn't selective about which fields to get out of table2, it just gets them all, whether required or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table2.*
```

is generally bad style - returning a lot of columns you are not interested in.  In this case it could be causing the slowness given the large number of (text) columns in this table.

100 columns * 150 characters * 1300 rows is roughly 19.5 MB, so the slowness could well be reading all the data from disk and transmitting it across the network.

Do you still see the slowness if you restrict this to the particular columns of table2 that you are interested in?

EDIT : your explain select output seems to confirm that it is not a difficult query to run, with only a small number of rows.  This makes the sheer data size of each row in table2 the most likely problem.  You can test this by removing / limiting the reference to table2.  If that is the case, then the only way to speed this query up will be to request fewer columns from table2.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. When I change the query from using "table2.*" to "table2.single_field", it takes <3 seconds - as compared to 1:38 in the original form. So looks like the software has to be changed to read only the columns it needs. Would it be any different without the ORDER BY? (I will try it, but my mysql server caches queries, so I have to wait a bit.)

Comment: I doubt removing the ORDER BY will make a difference...the size of data returned is still the same (unless you reduce the LIMIT to use fewer rows)

Comment: Hmm, ORDER BY does make a difference. Getting all the columns of table2, 30 rows, no ORDER BY, is instant. But when I add ORDER BY on a table2 field (indexed), it takes a long time again, and raises the load average. So it would seem that MySQL uses all columns in the sort, which doesn't make sense to me. EXPLAIN gives an empty Extra column in the case without ORDER BY, and when ORDER BY is part of the query, it gives "34387 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort".